# ssh connection closed immediately after successful login

Tags: ssh, fedora

I am running Fedora 18 and just set up a static IP address. With a dynamic IP address I was able to successfully use ssh, now however I get the message:

```
Last login: Thu Jul 11 12:56:39 2013 from quest.it.northwestern.edu
Connection to mahavira closed.
```

indicating a successful login followed immediately by the connection being closed.

The output of `ssh -vvv namu@mahavira` is:

```
[nkp@quser03 ~]$ ssh -vvv namu@mahavira 
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mahavira [xxx.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nkp/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/nkp/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/nkp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/nkp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 792 bytes for a total of 813
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 837
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 125/256
debug2: bits set: 516/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 981
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/nkp/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/nkp/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'mahavira' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nkp/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 509/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 997
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1045
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/nkp/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/nkp/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2abc51559610)
debug2: key: /home/nkp/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1109
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address xxx.xxx.xx.xx.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1205
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nkp/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/nkp/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/nkp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1573
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nkp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/nkp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
namu@mahavira's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 62 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1717
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 128 bytes for a total of 1845
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env MODULE_VERSION_STACK
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MODULE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env _LMFILES_
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KDE_IS_PRELINKED
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MODULEPATH
debug3: Ignored env MOABHOMEDIR
debug3: Ignored env LOADEDMODULES
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_ASKPASS
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env KRB5CCNAME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env PBS_DEFAULT
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env GXX_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env MODULESHOME
debug3: Ignored env PKG_CONFIG_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env INFOPATH
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env module
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 512 bytes for a total of 2357
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug1: channel 0: forcing write
Last login: Thu Jul 11 13:04:23 2013 from quest.it.northwestern.edu
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 2389
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2453
Connection to mahavira closed.
Transferred: sent 2224, received 2272 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 22447.6, received 22932.1
debug1: Exit status 254
```

I logged in physically to `mahavira` and there is no entry in the `/etc/hosts.allow`,  `/etc/hosts.deny`, or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files. The permission of `~/.ssh` directory is:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 namu namu 0 Jul 11 12:14 known_hosts
```

and the permissions of the contents of the `ssh` directory are:

```
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       4096 Jul 11 12:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 137 root root      12288 Jul 11 12:41 ..
-rw-------.   1 root root     245058 Jun 20 03:53 moduli
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root       2104 Jun 20 03:53 ssh_config
-rw-------.   1 root root       4375 Jun 20 03:53 sshd_config
-rw-r-----.   1 root ssh_keys    668 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root        590 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----.   1 root ssh_keys    965 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_key
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root        630 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_key.pub
-rw-r-----.   1 root ssh_keys   1679 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root        382 Apr 30 16:32 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The contents of `etc/ssh/sshd_config` are:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.87 2012/07/10 02:19:15 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
#Host *.local
#       CheckHostIP no

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

The most recent contents from `/var/log/secure` are:

```
Jul 11 13:05:25 mahavira sshd[22505]: Accepted password for namu from 165.124.130.7 port 50810 ssh2
Jul 11 13:05:25 mahavira sshd[22505]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user namu by (uid=0)
Jul 11 13:05:25 mahavira sshd[22505]: error: PAM: pam_open_session(): Permission denied
Jul 11 13:05:25 mahavira sshd[22509]: Received disconnect from 165.124.130.7: 11: disconnected by user
Jul 11 13:33:15 mahavira su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by namu(uid=1000)
```

It was pointed out that there is a PAM problem. The contents of `/etc/pam.d/sshd` are:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
```

The contents of `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` are:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

The contents of `/etc/pam.d/postlogin` are:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.


session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp silent
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

Comment: You're sure it changed after you changed the IP? The user does have a valid shell?

Comment: I can't be certain since I noticed that scp stopped working a few days ago and I just set up the static IP yesterday. The user does have a valid shell.

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?  Also could you show any relevent entries from /var/log/secure?

Comment: @RikSchneider, I just updated the post with the contents of the files.

Comment: The log says that there's a PAM problem. Check your pam config for ssh logins.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with session rules in PAM.  You may want to check what the session rules under /etc/pam.d look like.  Normally they would be in the files named /etc/pam.d/sshd and any files it refers to.

Comment: I added the contents of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. I didn't see any other file in the `pam.d` directory that maybe relevant, except maybe `password-auth`? I'm not sure what to make of the contents of the file. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The first column tells you when the module (rule) is applied.  THe second defines the action to take.  The third column is the module to use (e.g. pam_selinux.so) and its options or the name of another file to include.  There should be 2 more files named password-auth and postlogin.  What are the contents?

Comment: Thank you @RikSchneider. I just updated the post. Would it be worthwhile running `autoconfig` to get back the default settings (although I don't believe I changed anything here)?

Comment: I ran `autoconfig --test` and see that `pam_access is disabled`. Not sure if its relevant to the problem.

Comment: You may be able to fix it using authconfig.  Another option is to turn on debugging of the modules used.  Look at man pam_keyinit.so for information on using debug.  The output should be stored in /var/log/secure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9621/discussion-between-rik-schneider-and-namu)

Comment: @RikSchneider, thanks for the offer, but I just resolved the issue. It turned out that there was a naming discrepancy between the file `ifcfg-eth1` and the output of `ifconfig`. This is odd since I used the GUI to set up the static IP. Well now scp works just fine. :)

Comment: One favor.  Could you writeup your find and fix as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the way I set up my static IP address. I used the `Network` GUI and it created a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Wired_connection_2`. The output of ifconfig only showed entries under `lo` and `p6p1`. Typically, the file should have been created under the name of `ifcfg-p6p1`, but was not and oddly enough renaming it and rebooting my computer resolved the issue. [A static IP can always be manually set up](http://www.putorius.net/2012/10/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in.html), and for future reference for those that choose to take this path, the entries of the `ifcfg` file the OS created are listed below:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=xxx.xxx.xx.xx
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=xxx.xxx.xx.x
DNS1=xxx.xxx.xx.x
DNS2=xxx.xxx.xx.x
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=p6p1
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Note that most of the *x* entries can be obtained from the output of running the command `ifconfig` in terminal. Also, most of these variables are not required for setting up a static IP, but this is how the GUI did it.

Answer (score 3):

This seem to be a common problem when the user in `/etc/passwd` does not have a proper `SHELL` set. Check `/etc/passwd`.

```sh
# cat /etc/passwd

pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
sshd:x:107:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
...
```

If the last part show something other than *bash* or *sh* then you have a problem.

Comment: What is this `ssh-host-config`? My Fedora box doesn't have it.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Got confused answering different (but similar) question. Just ignore that.